# Aggregating Wildcards in Sumologic

Tags: aggregate, sumologic

I'm trying to aggregate the API logs based on the different endpoints I have. There are a total of 4 endpoints:

1: /v1/vehicle_locations

2: /v1/vehicle_locations/id

3: /v1/driver_locations

4: /v1/driver_locations/id

The way I'm currently doing this is:

`_sourceCategory=production | keyvalue auto | where (path matches "/v1/driver_locations" OR path matches "/v1/driver_locations/*" or path matches "/v1/vehicle_locations" or path matches "/v1/vehicle_locations/*")  | count by path`

The problem with this is that while I get the correct aggregate for `/v1/vehicle_locations` and `/v1/driver_locations`, I get individual results for `/v1/driver_locations/id` and `/v1/vehicle_locations/id` since the id is a wildcard. Is there a way I can aggregate these wildcards as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve what you ask. I think the most straightforward one and suggested is to use `| parse` operator so that you can treat the top-most element of your path as a field, e.g.

```
_sourceCategory=production
| keyvalue auto 
| parse field=path "*/*" as topmost, rest
| where (topmost = "vehicle_locations" or topmost = "driver_locations")
| count by topmost
```

Note that by default [`| parse` operator](https://help.sumologic.com/05Search/Search-Query-Language/01-Parse-Operators/01-Parse-Predictable-Patterns-Using-an-Anchor) works on the raw message (e.g. the original log line), but you can make it parse a field - using the `field=` syntax and this is what it's used above.

You might want to tweak the parse expression or use a regex depending on the actual paths you encounter.

(Disclaimer: I am currently employed by Sumo Logic)